# another meaning for "going after"

Tags: meaning

I searched [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/go-after) for "*going after someone*"; it means "to try to catch or stop someone". I'm not native. But is this the only meaning? Doesn't it mean "to look for someone" too?

As an example: Suppose there has been an accident in the nearby school and your little brother studies there. You want to go and check if he's OK, 
so you tell your mom, "I'll go after him, Mom." Is this correct?

Comment: Could you possibly add some context, please?

Comment: suppose there has been an accident in the nearby school and your little brother studies there. you want to go and check if he's ok and tell your mom "I'll go after him mom." is this correct?

Comment: Typically (but not exclusively), *to go after* is used in its idiomatic form: to pursue *aggressively*.

Comment: I wouldn't say aggressively – *pursue* is sufficient.

Comment: I'd probably just say, "*Ok Mom, I'll go [try to] find him.*"

Answer (score 0):

'Catch' doesn't always mean 'trap'. It can also mean just 'get to where they are'. (We often say 'catch up to' for this, to distinguish it from the 'trap' meaning, but just 'catch' works too.)

In your example most people would not say "I'll go after him" if the brother had clearly already arrived, but might say it if he had just set out. In that case "I'll catch him" works too.

These days "catch" can also mean just to "meet up with", as in "I'll catch you after the concert".

Answer (score 0):

*Go after* has several different uses:

- Taken literally, to follow:

> A: Would you like to go next?
>  B: No, I will **go after** you. (i.e,
>   after you're finished)

- To attack aggressively.  From *[Transformational Chairwork: Using Psychotherapeutic Dialogues in Clinical Practice](https://books.google.com/books?id=34jpBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=%22really%20go%20after%20him%22&source=bl&ots=e7P1egUTFw&sig=dc9uZXNA0VGFX26cb12uivjg4E0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj86MOG4anJAhWLGz4KHeliDwcQ6AEIMjAG#v=onepage&q=%22really%20go%20after%20him%22&f=false)* by Scott Kellogg:

> I will criticize him harshly for being inappropriate; and when he
>   fails at something, I really **go after** him. I also relentlessly
>   attack him for his past mistakes, errors, and failures.

- To chase and attempt to capture.  In several senses:

Literally, as reported in the *[Daily Mirror](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/go-hero-transport-boss-72-6195669)*, a man who was injured pursuing a car thief:

> "It was an automatic impulse **to go after** him."

Figuratively, with a lofty goal:

> **Go after** your dreams.

To capture [commercially](http://www.collegemarketing.net/category/marketing/youth-marketing/), usually a market segment:

> We can help a business target market any age group. Whether you want
>   **to go after** elementary school children, preteens, teens, college students, or young professionals, we can help.

To arrest and prosecute, as reported by *[The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/federal-eye/wp/2015/04/08/in-dallas-the-irs-says-it-cant-chase-tax-cheats-who-owe-less-than-1-million/)* on 4/8/15:

> The IRS says that $2 billion will go uncollected this year because of
>   cuts to revenue employees who **go after** tax cheats.

Answer (score -1):

A better single word synonym would be *chase*.

To use the context you suggested, elder sibling is actually *chasing*, *pursuing*, *trying to catch*, the younger brother.

Both the definition and your example are correct.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that *"There's been an accident at your brother's school and I don't know whether he's ok or not." "Ok, Mom, I'll go chase him for you."* would ***ever*** be uttered by anyone.

Comment: You'll have to explain. I cannot fathom why not.

Comment: Because as you say in your answer *chase* connotes *pursuing, trying to catch*  if your brother was porentially injured or worse, you would not be chasing after him you would be “checking on him” or “trying to find him” or “finding out for you” etc.  Also even if you were going to use *chase* I’d think it would be *chase after him* or *chase him down*  and not just plain *chase him*

Comment: @Jim If the elder brother is already at school, your criticism also applies to the example _go after_ suggested by the questioner. It's not my framing that's at fault here.

Comment: @Jim Your comment suggestion "find" is the best, really. I hadn't checked back until now, so I'd missed that.